# Changing Funding statement after acceptance

Tags: funding, ieee, acknowledgement

Does IEEE allow changing the Funding statement after the acceptance of the paper? (In particular, I am asking about IEEE transactions on nanotechnology.)

Comment: Probably best to ask them, and likely depends on where you're at in the process and what the change is.

Answer (score 1):

Ask them, but in short: You are free to change typos, grammar errors, and things such as acknowledgments, funding statements, author addresses, etc, that have no bearing on the *content* of the paper.